# asserting ownership of a Windows-shared hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mount, hard-drive, 17.04

I recently had to reinstall Windows and Ubuntu after a Windows Update wrecked everything. I'm more or less back up and running, but a shared hard drive is giving me problems. The drive works fine in Windows, but in Ubuntu it prevents me from changing the files (though I can still read them).

The file system on the drive is NTFS which might be part of the problem, but it also tells me that I don't have ownership of the drive.

Commands like this don't help:

```
sudo chown yourusername: /media/mountpoint
```

Or this (changing permissions with the Nautilus GUI)

```
gksudo nautilus
```

I have used the following command, when the drive is unmounted, in a fashion that gives me read-write access:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o user /dev/sdb1 /media/Elements
```

But it's not persistent, I'll have to do this every time and that's cumbersome!

Any suggestions? Can I wrest ownership back of the drive? Is there an option to save the mount user option above so it's that way every time?

[I'm tempted to follow the directions about editing my fstab based on this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424098/ownership-of-second-internal-hard-drive)

Links I got resources from:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1840948

[External drive mounts only as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769460/external-drive-mounts-only-as-root#)

Comment: Disable Fast Startup in Windows. If you disabled it before the update re-enabled it.

Comment: That's been done... with still now change to the ownership problem. I'm wondering if the previous version of Linux I had on that machine before the wipe is causing this. Linux Mint 18 was the previous.

Answer (score 0):

I did use the option of editing the fstab, from the Disks utility in Ubuntu 17.04. ([I found my info here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424098/ownership-of-second-internal-hard-drive))

It's in the screenshot, but I'll also post my entry to the fstab for reference:

```
defaults,auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,nls=utf8,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I opted for the umask=000 which might be too permissive, but since I have other users using this drive (logging into the same machine as their own users) I didn't want to accidentally lock it for them.

I'm not sure if the uid, gid, or umask made the difference; I had already applied ntfs-g using the Disks utility with no change to the problem, so I'm assuming it was a legacy user issue from when I had to reinstall windows and Linux.[image]